# UWP UserControl has correct size but isn't rendered

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, user-controls, uwp-xaml

I apologize if the answer to this question is simple, but I'm just beginning to learn UWP and really can't figure out a solution on my own.

I have a `UserControl` called `ClockWidget` included in a `Canvas` in my main page. When running the application, the control (containing only a `TextBlock`) has the correct size, but the text does not seem to be rendered.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="SmartMirror.IOT.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:widgets="using:SmartMirror.IOT.Widgets"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
        <widgets:ClockWidget Width="500" Height="150" />
    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

ClockWidget.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SmartMirror.IOT.Widgets.ClockWidget"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SmartMirror.IOT.Widgets"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:widgetData="using:SmartMirror.Shared.Model.WidgetData"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</UserControl>
```

Weirdly enough, in the preview of `ClockWidget.xaml`, everything is fine, but once inside of `MainPage.xaml`, it "disappears".

---

## Edit

I've added some screenshots to help clarify the issue.

As you can see, `ClockWidget.xaml` on its own seems to be working fine, the text shows up.
[image: ClockWidget.xaml]

However, once I slot it into `MainPage.xaml`, it does not show up. I have the `ClockWidget` selected in this screenshot, so as you can see, the size is still correct, but the `TextView` disappeared.
[image: MainPage.xaml]

Comment: I created a sample but I could not repro your issue,  Please try to set the `TextBlock`  Foreground property with obvious color. such as `Foreground="OrangeRed"`

Comment: Do you mean that you can not view it in VisualStudio or you can not view it in running?

Comment: @lindexi I have updated the question, please check it out

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft Did so without any results

Comment: Does the text show in the debug model?

Comment: I checked it in xaml designer, it could display. could you tried rebuild your project before open the xaml designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it had to, it boiled down to an *incredibly* stupid mistake. Inside my `ClockWidget.xaml.cs` code-behind, I overwrote the default constructor, but accidentally deleted the `InitializeComponent()` call. So obviously, the components were never initialized...

Thank you all for your help and support!